# Merge 2 GIT Branches

Tags: git, github, tortoisegit

I have a GIT requirement like this.

1. Need to create a Branch from a project which is not in the GIT right now : B1

Note : When I try to do this using TortoiseGit it gives this : `fatal not a valid object name : 'HEAD'`

2. Then I need to create an another Branch from the Master branch : B2

Note : I have done this task.

3. After that I need to merge Branch B1 to B2

Could you tell me how can I do this ? I'm not familiar with the GIT commands.My favourite Tool  is TortoiseGit Windows utility.Thanks.

Comment: @KeyWeeUsr Sorry not clear what you said here ? Can you elaborate it bit more ? Thanks.

Comment: @KeyWeeUsr `so just make that branch from master` did you mean B1 branch ? If Yes,then how can I add my new files to that ? Do I need to delete everything inside that and add my new files there ? Thanks.

Comment: @KeyWeeUsr Your solution worked.Can you put it as an answer ? Then I can close this post.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your steps are not well ordered, therefore we'd start with the easiest:

- create a branch from your master branch
- then create another branch in which you'll do some stuff with files - if it's something totally new, just delete everything and replace with your code, otherwise only add new stuff
- and in the end merge these branches

The way you described is really weird way how to merge things. Use some recommended steps on git/github or search "merge" here. When you see something with 500+ upvotes, you know you're there. :)

Comment: "When you see something with 500+ upvotes, you know you're there. :)" :-D like it

Comment: people here really love git, so yeah, these questions/answers are totally a gold mine for reputation here :D joking aside, you don't want to screw something up on company repo just because you thought the docs said this and in reality it ment something else for example...